# How to use Java MouseEvent Data

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, point, mouse-listeners

Sorry if this isn't the right website for this, but I've been learning Java lately and I have started to look at MouseEvents. I have got it working with the Data being output in the Console, but I have no idea how to use this Data. This is the data being output:

```
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(4,26),absolute(4,26),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame0
```

I need to access the "(4,26)" in the data, but I don't know how to go about this. The format of the data is MouseEvent.

Thanks, and again, sorry if this is the wrong website.

EDIT: This is the code used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.add(new main());
    jf.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // Mouse Pressed
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // Mouse Exit
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // Mouse Enter
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // General Click
        }
    });
    jf.setSize(Settings.map_width, Settings.map_height);
    jf.setTitle(Settings.frame_name);
    jf.setResizable(Settings.frame_resize);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: this is the right website.  please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so that we can see how you are obtaining the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Javadocs for MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) you'll see that it has a number of methods you can use to get information from the event.

`e.getX()` for example, would return `4` and `e.getY()` would return `26` given the code and event example you posted.

Comment: Edited.  See my comment to Adel.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew; I actually disagree. I link to Java6 docs on purpose because it's what most people are going to be using (And even that's a reach, I've seen plenty of places that are still standardized on Java5). I don't link to C++11 docs either unless the question is specifically about C++11.

Comment: The Java 7 docs. contain everything from either the Java 5 or 6 docs., with 2 additions: 1) they list new classes 2) **they show `@deprecated` flags**.  I highlit the 2nd point because if some method you are using in version `b` becomes deprecated in version `c` - deferring to a method introduced in version `a`, it makes sense to change the code designed for version `b` right now.  As 2 asides: 1) I am using V.6, but always refer to the V.7 docs. 2) The OP has *not stated* what version they are using.  But if you do not agree with my reasoning, I'll try to remember and *not* edit your posts.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I understand your reasoning and don't deny that you make a good argument. That being said, the issue that new methods are listed is the problem you can run into which then leads to "I did this and it gives me this error" followups. I don't think there's a perfect answer short of splitting out tags to specific versions ... which isn't optimal either. The problem of course becomes moot with wider adoption of J7, or at least the time factor being a good rationalization to move forward.

Comment: *"the issue that new methods are listed is the problem you can run into which then leads to "I did this and it gives me this error" followups."* 1) That is what **`@since`** tags are for. ;) 2) True, but the errors are pretty clear.

Comment: You're assuming that people who didn't read the docs in the first place would notice the @since tag, or read/understand the error messages. I find both to be ... untrue here :-D

Answer (score 1):

Had you checked the java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html), you would have known that the data you want to get is obtained by:

```
e.getX()
e.getY()
```

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).